# Improving state machine

Tags: java, switch-statement, state-machine

So I'd this state machine (on the next code some states are missing due they are not yet finished) with lot of almost identical states.
I'm sure there must be a better way of achieving this, but I can't find it out (may with classes but I'm not sure).

```
switch(firstState) {
    case INITIAL:
        if(c == 'g') {
            builder.append(c);
            firstState = FirstParserState.METHOD_G;
        }
        else if(c == 'p') {
            builder.append(c);
            firstState = FirstParserState.METHOD_P;
        }
        else
            firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

        break;
    case METHOD_G:
        if(c == 'e') {
            builder.append(c);
            firstState = FirstParserState.METHOD_E;
        }
        else
            firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

        break;
    case METHOD_E:
        if(c == 't') {
            builder.append(c);
            firstState = FirstParserState.METHOD_T;
        }
        else
            firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

        break;
    case METHOD_T:
        if(c == ' ') {
            method = builder.toString();
            builder.setLength(0);
            firstState = FirstParserState.WHISE_SPACE;
        }
        else
            firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

        break;
    case METHOD_P:
        if(c == 'o') {
            builder.append(c);
            firstState = FirstParserState.METHOD_O;
        }
        else
            firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

        break;
    case METHOD_O:
        if(c == 's') {
            builder.append(c);
            firstState = FirstParserState.METHOD_S;
        }
        else
            firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

        break;
    case METHOD_S:
        if(c == 't') {
            builder.append(c);
            firstState = FirstParserState.METHOD_T;
        }
        else
            firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

        break;
    case ERROR:
        ;//TODO: Dispatch error, malformed 1st line
        break;
}
```

Is it there any pattern I could apply? Or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm have to parse a HTTP request (using a state machine). This parses the first line (the code it's not complete).

Comment: Though EJP's answer is probably easiest and most efficient to implement, an alternative will be State pattern.  Each state is represented by an instance of State, and the state is responsible to do 1. the actual work (your `if (c==x) { build.append(c);}` stuff) 2. the state change

Comment: Thanks , but Is there a way to avoid creating a class per state (when using the state pattern)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should get rid of switch case part. You can implement state machine design pattern without creating a class for every state, there is one more elegant solution if you have many states : **enum based state machine**

Enum class implements `ParserStateListener.java` interface which includes methods can change object' states.

```
public enum FirstParserState implements ParserStateListener{

INITIAL{
    public void onEventChange(char c, StringBuilder builder, FirstParserState nextState) {
        if (c == 'g') {
            builder.append(c);
            nextState = FirstParserState.METHOD_G;
        } else if (c == 'p') {
            builder.append(c);
            nextState = FirstParserState.METHOD_P;
        } else
            nextState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

    }
},METHOD_G{
    public void onEventChange(char c, StringBuilder builder, FirstParserState nextState) {
        if (c == 'e') {
            builder.append(c);
            nextState = FirstParserState.METHOD_E;
        } else
            nextState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

    }
},METHOD_E{
    public void onEventChange(char c, StringBuilder builder, FirstParserState nextState) {
        if (c == 't') {
            builder.append(c);
            nextState = FirstParserState.METHOD_T;
        } else
            nextState = FirstParserState.ERROR;

    }
},ERROR{
    public void onEventChange(char c, StringBuilder sb, FirstParserState nextState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

}
```

This is listener class to keep actions which will change object state'

```
public interface ParserStateListener {

public void onEventChange(char c, StringBuilder sb, FirstParserState nextState);

}
```

Then you can just write your client codes :

```
 public void doOperations(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    FirstParserState firstParserState = FirstParserState.INITIAL;
    firstParserState.onEventChange(c, sb, firstParserState);        

}
```

This approach is just first look I don't know your exact requirements. If you need to call your `onEventChange(c, sb, firstParserState)` method for many times and if you already know your  transitions path, you can put your routes to a collection and just iterate by calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the code in each state which tests the input character and, in case of a match, accepts the input and sets up the next state:

```
if (c == ????) {
    builder.append(c);
    firstState = ????
}
```

You could move this logic into a method and eliminate three lines of code from your `switch` for each state/input combination.

Also, notice that every case has:

```
    else
        firstState = FirstParserState.ERROR;
```

You can eliminate these two lines from every state by using a `nextState` variable.  Before the `switch` you set `nextState = FirstParserState.ERROR`.  When an input matches, you  set the new state in `nextState` instead of directly in `firstState`. 
If no input matches, the individual states don't need to do anything special because `nextState` will already be `FirstParserState.ERROR`. Then after the `switch` you set `firstParserState = nextState` to prepare for the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need a *state table* which maps the current state and the current input character to the next state. Then all you have to do is switch on the next state and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks I may give it a try, depending on the possible implementations of the state pattern.